# Supporting auto rotation on iPhone views

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, autorotate

To support auto-rotation on all views, what should one do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this tutorial. This helped me a lot in understanding the Autorotation and Autosizing Options.

http://www.bogotobogo.com/XcodeSDK-Chapter4.html

Comment: For a more up-to-date version, see Ch5 of "Beginning iOS 5 Development: Exploring the iOS SDK", the book on which this tutorial is based.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in all of your view controllers.

```
  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
      return YES;
  }
```

Comment: What about the scrolling on some views. Will all the custom views also be adjusted themselves?